# Is there a way to use WHERE with INSERT INTO?

Tags: mysql

I want to use MySQL as some sort of timetable and I already built an SQL Table like this:

```
+------+--------+---------+-----------+----------+--------+
| TIME | MONDAY | TUESDAY | WEDNESDAY | THURSDAY | FRIDAY |
+------+--------+---------+-----------+----------+--------+
|    1 | NULL   | NULL    | NULL      | NULL     | NULL   |
|    2 | NULL   | NULL    | NULL      | NULL     | NULL   |
|    3 | NULL   | NULL    | NULL      | NULL     | NULL   |
|    4 | NULL   | NULL    | NULL      | NULL     | NULL   |
|    5 | NULL   | NULL    | NULL      | NULL     | NULL   |
|    6 | NULL   | NULL    | NULL      | NULL     | NULL   |
|    7 | NULL   | NULL    | NULL      | NULL     | NULL   |
|    8 | NULL   | NULL    | NULL      | NULL     | NULL   |
|    9 | NULL   | NULL    | NULL      | NULL     | NULL   |
+------+--------+---------+-----------+----------+--------+
```

This is what I get when using `SELECT`. Now I want to insert data in a specific field.

I tried `INSERT INTO timetable (MONDAY) WHERE TIME=1` but it didn't work, and after some Google research I got the information that it is not possible to use `WHERE` in combination with `INSERT INTO`.

Is there a way to insert data into a specific field or another way of using `WHERE`?

Comment: What you are looking for is an opportunity to seriously rethink your schema. A database table IS NOT a spreadsheet

Comment: By the meaning of the task you need UPDATE, not INSERT.

Comment: @Strawberry do you know if there's any other way to do this with MySQL?

Comment: A standard approach would be with 3 columns: (day,time,value)

Comment: What should be the expected output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use UPDATE query for updated the selected row(s).

**Query:**

```
UPDATE timetable SET monday='classes available' WHERE time=1;
```

Here I insert sample data 'classes available' when time=1